# ADB2C identity experience framework : access token use just after an authentification

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

we are using lots of ADB2C built-in policies and wanna now switch on custom policies thanks to the Identity Experience Framework.

One of our use-cases is: make some calls (from the policy) on endpoints (that are protected by access token) just after an authentication (signup or signin). For example : just after the signup we would like to call an api for the privacy policy management. In order to have it working, we need to have the access token.

Is there a way, thanks to custom policies, to call an http endpoint with the access token just issued right after the authentication ?

Comment: Hi. Do you mean to call the HTTP endpoint during the authentication flow or after the authentication flow has completed and the access token has been issued?

Comment: Hi, if I'm not wrong it should be after. Step 1: the user create its account thanks to the custom policies. The client application received the authorization code. Step 2 : the client application call the /token endpoint of the custom policy with grant_type "authorization_code" in order to get an access/id token. The custom policy will provide to the app the different tokens and will also call some endpoints   for which we also need the access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an access token or id token is generated by Identity Experience Framework (IEF), it signifies that all requirements of the user journey were met. That is, if the user journey required some privacy policy management and user needed to consent to it, only then would the access token or id token be generated.

The scenario that you are mentioning could be achieved by IEF calling the privacy policy management API using service-to-service trust and passing user's identity by other means, such as objectId in header or in the body.

Because IEF is directly calling the Rest API, it is unclear how IEF generating a token and sending that to the Rest API is more beneficial than IEF making a request over SSL and providing user's data.